How can a ring oscillator's frequency be inversely proportional to supply voltage?
I was reading this paper on Ring Oscillators, when I came across the following statement on the first page :

since the delay of an inverter falls as the supply voltage \$V_{DD}\$ increases, the oscillation frequency \$f_0\$ is inversely proportional to \$V_{DD}\$.

Is this just a typo? Because as I seem to understand it, as the supply voltage increases, the propagation delay decreases (Slide 7 for reference) and hence the frequency which is inversely proportional to the delay, would increase; hence, the frequency would be directly proportional to the supply voltage.

Yes it seems to be a typo. If the delay decreases the frequency should increase.

@Uwe perhaps the paper was referring to the switching voltage. In this question : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691413/mosfet-ring-oscillator-lt-spice , the user points to an equation which shows that frequency of the oscillator is inversely proportional to its switching voltage
